# Decision making in C - the ? : Operator example

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, ternary-operator

I know how the operator works, but I dont understand how the second case in the code below gives a 1 as a result.

```
#define MIN(a,b) a<b ? a:b  
int x = MIN(1,2);  //case 1, output is 1
int x = MIN(1,1+1); // case 2
```

Shouldnt the compiler see this (case 2) as "is 1<1+1?", which I think should be "is 1<1? No it is not", expression 3 is executed and we get: "b" = 1+1 = 2. This is because there are no parentheses around a and b in the macro above, or maybe because I am following my own rules and feel lost? Help please....

Also, how do you explain this case:

```
int x = MIN(1,2) + 1;  //should we consider the "1" on the right?
```

Comment: Use parenthesis in macro definition. `#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b)) ? (a):(b)) `

Answer (score 8):

Your second case

```
 MIN(1,1+1);
```

expands to

```
 1<1+1 ? 1:1+1;
```

Since `1<1+1` is evaluated to true the expression above results in `1`.

---

The statement

```
int x = MIN(1,2) + 1;
```

results after expansion in

```
int x = 1<2 ? 1:2 + 1;
```

the operator `+` has higher precedence than the *ternary operator* `:?`, so the expression below is actually equivalent to

```
1<2 ? 1:(2 + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldnt the compiler see this(case 2) as "is 1<1+1?", which I think should be "is 1<1? No it is not"

No. `+` has higher precendence than `<` (and both have higher precendence than `?:`). The statement

```
1 < 1 + 1 ? 1 : 1 + 1
```

Is the same as

```
(1 < (1 + 1)) ? 1 : (1 + 1)
```